# Applescript to get body of a message in Outlook 2011

Tags: email, outlook, applescript

I need to use applescript to process the body of an email during incoming.
How can I get the body of an email when using Outlook 2011?

I am totally new to Applescript.

Any tutorial for using Applescript with Outlook 2011 or starter code for this question would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set theText to string
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set messages to selection
    repeat with this_message in messages
        set theText to content of this_message
    end repeat
end tell
```

Now theText has the contents of the message.